# Filter on multiple flags in EF Core C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, flags

So we have a flag value like this:

```
[Flag]
public enum Status
{
    New = 1,
    Available = 2,
    Unavailable= 4,
    Inactive = 8,
}
```

From the front-end we get for example two values. If an entity has one of those values or both values. Then we should return it. The values are in the filter.Statuses what is an `List<Status>`. Ofcourse it can also be that there are no filters so we check if there is atleas one filter. Also it is not an required field in the DB. So we check if it has value also. So we do an where condition like this:

```
entity => (filter.Statuses.Count <= 0 || (entity.Status.HasValue && filter.Statuses.Any(c =>  entity .Status.Value.HasFlag(c))))
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'c => EntityShaperExpression: 
    App.Domain.Entity
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.Status.Value.HasFlag((Enum)c)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I've tried writing it in multiple different ways. But still not able to filter all the entities that have one or multiple of the given statuses.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Please add a matching tag (like [ef-core-xx]).

Comment: we are using ef-core-7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

EF Core should be able to translate the HasFlag method to SQL. However, if you are facing an error "could not be translated", it's possible that EF Core doesn't support the HasFlag method for your specific database provider.

You can use bitwise operators for workaround:

```
Status filterStatus = filter.Statuses.Aggregate(Status.New, (current, status) => current | status);

var filteredEntities = context.MyEntities
    .Where(e => (e.Status & filterStatus) != 0)
```

Comment: According to the issues of the efcore repo this is implemented in EF Core 1.1.0. See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2852.

Also this will make the entity needs to have both values. But it should also return if it has just one of the two give flags.